# Intermittent connection issue between MongoDB pods

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes-pod, bitnami

I have two deployments of MongoDB in the same namespace :

1. a. MongoDB instance to be periodically backed up
   (mongodb-deployment-79bdf489d8-klyo7)
2. CronJob to do the backups
   (mongo-backup-toolset-75f8f679dd-abc2d)

NB : CronJob Deployment uses mongosh and thus has a Mongo container also

For backups I will run the following command as part of the CronJob's logic :

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://admin:abc123@mongo-single-clusterip/platforms" --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip --out /tmp/dump-12-06-22/mybackup.gz
```

Before fully implementing CronJob I first deployed it as a ***plain MongoDB container** -- why -- because I have to test connection between the two pods first -- If its authenticating successfully*.
I am testing the connection by executing into the CronJob container :

```
kubectl exec -it mongo-backup-toolset-75f8f679dd-abc2d -- sh

mongo mongodb://admin:abc123@mongo-single-clusterip/platforms?authSource=admin
```

CronJob definition :
[CronJob manifest](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z3F1zUMWRbQhoHubfcEJYB4p5Kku-iPQ/view?usp=sharing)

Deployment to be backed up has the following definition:
[MongoInstance manifest](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vm_aQ8TCu85TeZlnLmC1lqTwxObhXcgj/view?usp=sharing)

### Expected behavior?

A login attempt executed from **mongo-backup-toolset-75f8f679dd-abc2d** should authenticate successfully and consistently between different sessions. If this is working the corresponding mongodump command should also execute and authenticate consistently since it will be using the same MongoDB-URI and credentials :

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://admin:abc123@mongo-single-clusterip/platforms" --authenticationDatabase admin --gzip --out /tmp/dump-12-06-22/mybackup.gz
```

### What do you see instead?

The connection is intermittent . Sometimes the toolset pod connects/authenticates successfully , sometimes it fails with error :

```
mongo mongodb://admin:abc123@mongo-single-clusterip/platforms?authSource=admin MongoDB shell version v4.4.6 connecting to: mongodb://mongo-single-clusterip:27017/platforms?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb Error: Authentication failed. : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17 @(connect):2:6 exception: connect failed exiting with code 1
```

Below is a screenshot of this behavior. I logged in successfully and did a proper logout but authentication fails on the subsequent attempt :
[image: IntermittentConnection]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presented connection URIs are correct. The cause of the intermittent connection was an issue in the cluster networking and not anything to do with the mongo images. The pods can now connect without issues.